# Rgraphviz library loading error

Tags: r

I have a question about `Rgraphviz`. After installing `Graphviz` and `Rgraphviz` correctly, I can not load the `Rgraphviz` library. The error looks like this:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rgraphviz', details:
  call: value[[3L]](cond)
  error: unable to load shared object     '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rgraphviz/libs/x86_64/Rgraphviz.so':

dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rgraphviz/libs/x86_64
  /Rgraphviz.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgvc.5.dylib

  Referenced from:         
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/Rgraphviz/libs/x86_64/Rgraph  viz.so

 Reason: image not found

Check that (1) graphviz is installed on your system; (2) the
installed version of graphviz matches '2.26.3'; this is the version
used to build this Rgraphviz package; (3) graphviz is accessible to
R, e.g., the path to the graphviz 'bin' directory is in the system
'PATH' variable.  See additional instructions in the 'README' file of
the Rgraphviz 'source' distribution, available at

 http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html

Ask further questions on the Bioconductor mailing list

http://bioconductor.org/docs/mailList.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if Graphviz is installed on the same **path** R is looking for. If it's not, you should

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = path_to_graphviz
```

Before calling R. Or add this line to your bash profile in order run it automatically.